# Is there a word for “making two conflicting elements coexist together in a system”?

Tags: single-word-requests

The conflicting elements are integrated into a system, but their conflicts are not really resolved. Instead they are somehow made to coexist with some hackish way.

Example:
Hypocrisy, both as a self deception and a social deception, is a mechanism to **WORD** the conflicting forces of self interests and the social interests demanded from oneself.

I tried "accommodate, cope, coordinate" but none of them seems right.

Comment: How about ***rationalize***?

Comment: ***Harmonize***.

Comment: @DanBron - I had originally suggested harmonize but deleted it because hpocrisy does not provide harmony between self interest and social interests.

Comment: @Jim But a hypocrisy is not a rationalization, which is an attempt to reconcile the logic, if fallaciously.

Comment: @arthurtea - Point taken. I think your basic premise is flawed in that hypocrisy does not make two conflicting elements coexist together.  The two conflicting elements already exist, and hypocrisy comes to play when the conflict is noticed and "***called out***".  So for your sentence: *call out*, *point out*, *shine a light on*  etc.

Comment: 'Detente' was what was used for this during the Cold War.

Comment: [Thesis - antithesis - synthesis](https://www.google.com/search?q=thesis+antithesis+synthesis)

Answer (score 6):

There are several options, depending on the precise connotations you prefer. I might start with [***reconcile***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/reconcile). From *Cambridge Dictionary*:

> *verb* to adjust the way you think about a fact or situation that is opposed to another fact or situation so that you can accept both:
>   *How do we reconcile the seemingly contradictory notions of cutting taxes and balancing the budget?*

This is a particularly apt option if you want to emphasize the fact that the two concepts were (or are generally) at odds with one another, but have figured out a way to live with one another.

You said that [***accommodate***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/accommodate) doesn't quite work; I could make it fit your example, in the sense

> 2. To take into consideration or make adjustments for; allow for: *an economic proposal that accommodates the interests of senior citizens.*

(From *The American Heritage Dictionary*, via The FreeDictionary.com)

But *accommodate*, to me, suggests finding room for both concepts without necessarily an implication of direct conflict between the two. I think this may be why it doesn't quite work for you, and might possibly make *reconcile* seem too strongly "settled" a term, as well.

If that's correct, then you might want to consider ***negotiate*** or ***mediate***, both of which emphasize the ongoing struggle and uneasy co-existence between the two concepts. This is a bit of a specialist use of these words, mostly seen in academic-type texts, as in

> In our attempt to address the anxiety this provokes and to reintegrate ourselves to the external world, we develop a symbolic system to **negotiate** our conflicting drives of creation and destruction toward self and other. ([Dina Georgis, *The Better Story: Queer Affects from the Middle East*, 2013](https://books.google.com/books?id=RPiMWzT0tvQC&lpg=PA156&dq=negotiate%20%22conflicting%20drives%22&pg=PA156#v=onepage&q=negotiate%20%22conflicting%20drives%22&f=false))

or

> Institutions **mediate** conflicting desires, and differing institutions will generate differences in outcomes even under the same preference orderings. ([Robert Pahre, *Democratic Foreign Policy Making: Problems of Divided Government and International Cooperation*, 2006](https://books.google.com/books?id=jLSGDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA87&dq=mediate%20%22conflicting%20desires%22&pg=PA87#v=onepage&q=mediate%20%22conflicting%20desires%22&f=false))

Because one can negotiate for oneself but a mediator is, by definition, a third party, I would say that *negotiate* has a bit more of a connotation of volition on the part of the main actor, whereas *mediate* has more of an implication of an outside force. In your example, *negotiate* sounds more like hypocrisy is the individual's or society's *own*, perhaps semi-conscious, mechanism; whereas *mediate* feels very slightly more automatic, or passive in the non-grammatical sense.

---

All of these terms are related to the concept of *compromise*, and you could also look at its synonyms and related terms for more ideas. You could also rewrite your sentence to use *compromise* itself, e.g. *a mechanism to **reach a compromise between** the conflicting forces* etc.

Comment: The problem with **reconcile** or **negotiate** is that there is really no reconciliation or compromise going on within a hypocrite. We are just lying to ourselves and others; sweeping things under the rug; hacking together the setup. So a more mechanical verb seems more appropriate. Perhaps **accommodate** and **mediate** are the closest I can get.

Answer (score 1):

> Juxtapose:
>
> to put things that are not similar next to each other

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/juxtapose

Hypocrisy, both as a self deception and a social deception, is a mechanism to **juxtapose** the conflicting forces of self interests and the social interests demanded from oneself.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good starting point, since your desired connotation isn't entirely clear, would be to look at synonyms of "**Integrate**" - or perhaps "integrate" itself works for you.

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/integrate

Words like "join" and "combine" feel too weak for the point you're probably trying to make, whereas words like "fuse" and "meld" feel too jargon-ish and physical.

I know this thread is old, but I didn't feel like the question was definitively resolved for people who land on this page in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not think g of the word - paradox? When two things appear to be in conflict with each other, but in reality, are not.

Comment: A **paradox** is when things confict, but it does not answer the question *Is there a word for “making two conflicting elements coexist together in a system”?*

Answer (score 0):

The word "[ameliorate](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/ameliorate)" (to make something better) could be used in this context:

> Example: Hypocrisy, both as a self deception and a social deception, is a mechanism to **ameliorate** the conflicting forces of self interests and the social interests demanded from oneself.

In this sentence, it adds a bit of irony because who would think of hypocrisy making anything better?

Answer (score -1):

Nobody ever gets the word I would use when I look here...It's sooooo er...what's the word?
Anyhow 'ambivalent' or 'contradictory', 'unresolved', 'non conforming'.
My favourite is ambivalent though. He was full of ambivalence..
Belated too is appropriate for 30 months late.

Comment: How do these words fit in the example sentence?